# Fresh init React Native Build has CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler error on Xcode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Recently, Apple released Xcode to version **12**, and after update from **11.7** to **12.0.1** all of the React Native applications cannot build on a simulator, even a fresh initialized React Native project on a simulator with an earlier version of iOS, actually, I build it on a simulator iPhone 11 with iOS 13.5 but only I got this error:

> CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler

**Full Log**:

```
Showing Recent Issues
CompileC /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o Kelaket/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-simulator -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DFB_SONARKIT_ENABLED=1 -DFB_SONARKIT_ENABLED=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -index-store-path /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Kelaket-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Kelaket-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Kelaket-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Kelaket-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaAsyncSocket -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLibEvent -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBLazyVector -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBReactNativeSpec -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-DoubleConversion -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Glog -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-PeerTalk -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-RSocket -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FlipperKit -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/OpenSSL-Universal -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTRequired -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTSystemSetting -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNCAsyncStorage -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNCMaskedView -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNGestureHandler -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNReanimated -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNScreens -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNSentry -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RNVectorIcons -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Sentry -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/YogaKit -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-blur -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-orientation-locker -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-safe-area-context -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-slider -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/toolbar-android -I/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core -I/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -fmodule-map-file=/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap -fmodule-map-file=/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FlipperKit/FlipperKit.modulemap -fmodule-map-file=/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.dia -c /Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Kelaket/AppDelegate.m -o /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o

In file included from /Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Kelaket/AppDelegate.m:26:
In file included from /Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-orientation-locker/Orientation.h:13:
In file included from /Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:9:
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTJSInvokerModule.h:14:64: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
@property (nonatomic, copy, nonnull) void (^invokeJS)(NSString *module, NSString *method, NSArray *args);
                                                               ^
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTJSInvokerModule.h:14:64: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
@property (nonatomic, copy, nonnull) void (^invokeJS)(NSString *module, NSString *method, NSArray *args);
                                                               ^
                                                                 _Nullable 
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTJSInvokerModule.h:14:64: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
@property (nonatomic, copy, nonnull) void (^invokeJS)(NSString *module, NSString *method, NSArray *args);
                                                               ^
                                                                 _Nonnull 
In file included from /Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Kelaket/AppDelegate.m:26:
In file included from /Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/react-native-orientation-locker/Orientation.h:13:
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:17:39: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
@property (nonatomic, weak) RCTBridge *bridge;
                                      ^
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:17:39: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
@property (nonatomic, weak) RCTBridge *bridge;
                                      ^
                                        _Nullable 
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:17:39: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
@property (nonatomic, weak) RCTBridge *bridge;
                                      ^
                                        _Nonnull 
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:25:24: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents;
                       ^
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:25:24: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents;
                       ^
                        _Nullable
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:25:24: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents;
                       ^
                        _Nonnull
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:31:37: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
- (void)sendEventWithName:(NSString *)name body:(id)body;
                                    ^
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:31:37: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
- (void)sendEventWithName:(NSString *)name body:(id)body;
                                    ^
                                     _Nullable
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:31:37: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
- (void)sendEventWithName:(NSString *)name body:(id)body;
                                    ^
                                     _Nonnull
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:31:50: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
- (void)sendEventWithName:(NSString *)name body:(id)body;
                                                 ^
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:31:50: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
- (void)sendEventWithName:(NSString *)name body:(id)body;
                                                 ^
                                                    _Nullable 
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:31:50: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
- (void)sendEventWithName:(NSString *)name body:(id)body;
                                                 ^
                                                    _Nonnull 
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:41:31: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
- (void)addListener:(NSString *)eventName;
                              ^
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:41:31: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
- (void)addListener:(NSString *)eventName;
                              ^
                               _Nullable
/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTEventEmitter.h:41:31: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
- (void)addListener:(NSString *)eventName;
                              ^
                               _Nonnull
6 warnings generated.

Ld /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.app/Kelaket normal x86_64
    cd /Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphonesimulator -L -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Glog -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-PeerTalk -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-RSocket -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlipperKit -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTSystemSetting -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTTypeSafety -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCAsyncStorage -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCMaskedView -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNGestureHandler -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNScreens -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSentry -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-CoreModules -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAnimation -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTBlob -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTLinking -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTNetwork -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTSettings -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTText -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTVibration -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-cxxreact -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsiexecutor -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsinspector -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sentry -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blur -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-orientation-locker -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-safe-area-context -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-slider -L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/toolbar-android -L/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/CocoaLibEvent/lib -L/Users/amer/WebstormProjects/Kelaket/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib -F/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Kelaket.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Kelaket_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lCocoaAsyncSocket -lDoubleConversion -lFBReactNativeSpec -lFlipper -lFlipper-DoubleConversion -lFlipper-Folly -lFlipper-Glog -lFlipper-PeerTalk -lFlipper-RSocket -lFlipperKit -lFolly -lRCTSystemSetting -lRCTTypeSafety -lRNCAsyncStorage -lRNCMaskedView -lRNGestureHandler -lRNReanimated -lRNScreens -lRNSentry -lRNVectorIcons -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReactCommon -lSentry -lYoga -lYogaKit -lc++ -lcrypto -levent -levent_core -levent_extra -levent_pthreads -lglog -lreact-native-blur -lreact-native-orientation-locker -lreact-native-safe-area-context -lreact-native-slider -lssl -lstdc++ -ltoolbar-android -lz -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework JavaScriptCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework UIKit -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Kelaket.app-Simulated.xcent -framework AdSupport -lsqlite3.0 -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreData -lPods-Kelaket -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Kelaket.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Kelaket_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kelaket.app/Kelaket

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/amer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kelaket-bnijepnppqknjudozlfgpwgknyck/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket'
ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How I can settle this issue?

Comment: What is the actual error.  Provide the log if you don't know.  The line you provided is expected and not an error.  It is informative text about the build.

Comment: In the log I see instructions how to fix your problems.I'd fix them.

Comment: Dear @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia, I add a full log to post.

Comment: Dear @gnasher729, Do you mean, you know what is the solution?

Comment: From the logs you use `CocoaAsyncSocket`. Do you use cocoa pods? Have you run `pod install' for ios?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was for version 12, and it is disappeared in version 13.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this question is for earlier builds of Xcode version 12, and this issue is  disappeared in version 13.x

I doubt anyone use version 12, but for fixing on Xcode 12, running and debugging on physical device could be a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the log is:

```
ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket
```

This means that the linker failed to locate libCocoaAsyncSocket in the linker search path.  You need to first build this library (eg: make the target that builds it a dependency the target that links against it.  Or you must otherwise ensure the library is present at build time.

Comment: Dear Jeremy, would you mind if I ask you to delete this answer? because I tried to delete my question but SO told me I cannot because of your answer.